# What does "make oldconfig" do exactly in the Linux kernel makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel

Can anyone explain what the target "oldconfig" does exactly in the Linux kernel makefile?  I see it referenced in some build documentation but never explained what it does exactly.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

It reads the existing `.config` file that was used for an old kernel and prompts the user for options in the current kernel source that are not found in the file. This is useful when taking an existing configuration and moving it to a new kernel.

Answer (score 40):

**Summary**

As mentioned [by Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4178568/895245), it updates your `.config` for you after you update the kernel source, e.g. with `git pull`.

It tries to keep your existing options.

Having a script for that is helpful because:

- new options may have been added, or old ones removed
- the kernel's Kconfig configuration format has options that:

  - imply one another via `select`
  - depend on another via `depends`

  Those option relationships make manual config resolution even harder.

**Let's modify .config manually to understand how it resolves configurations**

First generate a default configuration with:

```
make defconfig
```

Now edit the generated `.config` file manually to emulate a kernel update and run:

```
make oldconfig
```

to see what happens. Some conclusions:

1. Lines of type:

   ```
   # CONFIG_XXX is not set
   ```

   are not mere comments, but actually indicate that the parameter is not set.

   For example, if we remove the line:

   ```
   # CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO is not set
   ```

   and run `make oldconfig`, it will ask us:

   ```
   Compile the kernel with debug info (DEBUG_INFO) [N/y/?] (NEW)
   ```

   When it is over, the `.config` file will be updated.

   If you change any character of the line, e.g. to `# CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO`, it does not count.
2. Lines of type:

   ```
   # CONFIG_XXX is not set
   ```

   are always used for the negation of a property, although:

   ```
   CONFIG_XXX=n
   ```

   is also understood as the negation.

   For example, if you remove `# CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO is not set` and answer:

   ```
   Compile the kernel with debug info (DEBUG_INFO) [N/y/?] (NEW)
   ```

   with `N`, then the output file contains:

   ```
   # CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO is not set
   ```

   and not:

   ```
   CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=n
   ```

   Also, if we manually modify the line to:

   ```
   CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=n
   ```

   and run `make oldconfig`, then the line gets modified to:

   ```
   # CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO is not set
   ```

   without `oldconfig` asking us.
3. Configs whose dependencies are not met, do not appear on the `.config`. All others do.

   For example, set:

   ```
   CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
   ```

   and run `make oldconfig`. It will now ask us for: `DEBUG_INFO_REDUCED`, `DEBUG_INFO_SPLIT`, etc. configs.

   Those properties did not appear on the `defconfig` before.

   If we look under `lib/Kconfig.debug` where they are defined, we see that they depend on `DEBUG_INFO`:

   ```
   config DEBUG_INFO_REDUCED
       bool "Reduce debugging information"
       depends on DEBUG_INFO
   ```

   So when `DEBUG_INFO` was off, they did not show up at all.
4. Configs which are `selected` by turned on configs are automatically set without asking the user.

   For example, if `CONFIG_X86=y` and we remove the line:

   ```
   CONFIG_ARCH_MIGHT_HAVE_PC_PARPORT=y
   ```

   and run `make oldconfig`, the line gets recreated without asking us, unlike `DEBUG_INFO`.

   This happens because `arch/x86/Kconfig`  contains:

   ```
   config X86
       def_bool y
       [...]
       select ARCH_MIGHT_HAVE_PC_PARPORT
   ```

   and select forces that option to be true. See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117521/select-vs-depends-in-kernel-kconfig
5. Configs whose constraints are not met are asked for.

   For example, `defconfig` had set:

   ```
   CONFIG_64BIT=y
   CONFIG_RCU_FANOUT=64
   ```

   If we edit:

   ```
   CONFIG_64BIT=n
   ```

   and run `make oldconfig`, it will ask us:

   ```
   Tree-based hierarchical RCU fanout value (RCU_FANOUT) [32] (NEW)
   ```

   This is because `RCU_FANOUT` is defined at `init/Kconfig` as:

   ```
   config RCU_FANOUT
       int "Tree-based hierarchical RCU fanout value"
       range 2 64 if 64BIT
       range 2 32 if !64BIT
   ```

   Therefore, without `64BIT`, the maximum value is `32`, but we had `64` set on the `.config`, which would make it inconsistent.

**Bonuses**

`make olddefconfig` sets every option to their default value without asking interactively. It gets run automatically on `make` to ensure that the `.config` is consistent in case you've modified it manually like we did. See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/116299/automatically-answer-defaults-when-doing-make-oldconfig-on-a-kernel-tree

`make alldefconfig` is like `make olddefconfig`, but it also accepts a config fragment to merge. This target is used by the `merge_config.sh` script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39440863/895245

And if you want to automate the `.config` modification, that is not too simple: [How do you non-interactively turn on features in a Linux kernel .config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505164/how-do-you-non-interactively-turn-on-features-in-a-linux-kernel-config-file)

Answer (score 29):

Before you run `make oldconfig`, you need to copy a kernel configuration file from an older kernel into the root directory of the new kernel.

You can find a copy of the old kernel configuration file on a running system at `/boot/config-3.11.0`. Alternatively, kernel source code has configs in `linux-3.11.0/arch/x86/configs/{i386_defconfig / x86_64_defconfig}`

If your kernel source is located at `/usr/src/linux`:

```
cd /usr/src/linux
cp /boot/config-3.9.6-gentoo .config
make oldconfig
```

Comment: Dont build the kernel as root! see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fMeH7wqOwXA#t=15m44s

Answer (score 4):

Updates an old config with new/changed/removed options.

Answer (score 1):

From this [page](http://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2011-August/003089.html):

> Make oldconfig takes the .config and runs it through the rules of the
>   Kconfig files and produces a .config which is consistant with the
>   Kconfig rules. If there are CONFIG values which are missing, the make
>   oldconfig will ask for them.
>
> If the .config is already consistant with the rules found in Kconfig,
>   then make oldconfig is essentially a no-op.
>
> If you were to run make oldconfig, and then run make oldconfig a
>   second time, the second time won't cause any additional changes to be
>   made.

Answer (score 1):

It's torture. Instead of including a generic conf file, they make you hit return 9000 times to generate one.

Comment: Try: `yes "" | make oldconfig`

Comment: `make olddefconfig` is probably what you want :-)