# How do you non-interactively turn on features in a Linux kernel .config file?

Tags: linux, build, linux-kernel

I have a situation where our software needs to work with several different Linux kernel distributions / kernel trees. (including Android forks)

In trying to automate our build process, I am finding that some of the `defconfig` files for particular builds we need to support do not include the kernel modules we depend on.

For example, let's imagine I need an option called `XXX` in my `.config`. For some dependencies, I can do something like this:

```
sed -i 's/# CONFIG_XXX is not set/CONFIG_XXX=m/' .config
```

For others, it's not so easy since the dependency may span multiple lines of `.config` statements.

Is there a more supported way to do this non-interactively, or am I stuck writing a more complex search-and-replace script?

Comment: Can you just create a set of .config files with the correct contents for each build?

Comment: @ed., not a bad idea. I'd rather not, though, as I need to support a large variety of kernels and it would be quite a bit more work to have a separate default `.config` for each one, given that I just need to include a couple of extra configuration options. (It's just that they often explode into a huge number of sub-options which also must be modified, and I don't know if the option names in the `.config` will change between kernel releases.) I guess that's a good argument for creating a `.config` by hand for each supported kernel build, though. ;-)

Comment: You could create some by hand and use diff/patch to modify similar ones. Maybe...

Comment: @ed., good idea. If the patch doesn't apply cleanly, I can call it out as a build failure.

Answer (score 17):

The kernel has a tool (./scripts/config) to change specific options on .config. Here is an example:

```
./scripts/config --set-val CONFIG_OPTION y
```

Although, it doesn't check the validity of the .config file.

Answer (score 7):

**[`merge_config.sh`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.7/scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh) config fragments**

```
$ cd linux
$ git checkout v4.9
$ make x86_64_defconfig
$ grep -E 'CONFIG_(DEBUG_INFO|GDB_SCRIPTS)[= ]' .config
# CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO is not set
$ # GDB_SCRIPTS depends on CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO in lib/Kconfig.debug.
$ cat <<EOF >.config-fragment
> CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
> CONFIG_GDB_SCRIPTS=y
> EOF
$ # Order is important here. Must be first base config, then fragment.
$ ./scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh .config .config-fragment
$ grep -E 'CONFIG_(DEBUG_INFO|GDB_SCRIPTS)[= ]' .config
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
CONFIG_GDB_SCRIPTS=y
```

Process substitution does *not* work unfortunately:

```
./scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig \
    <( printf 'CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y\nCONFIG_GDB_SCRIPTS=y\n' )
```

because of: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164109/32558

`merge_config.sh` is a simple front-end for the `make alldefconfig` target.

When cross compiling, `ARCH` must be exported when you run `merge_config.sh`, e.g.:

```
export ARCH=arm64
export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
make defconfig
./scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh .config .config-fragment
```

The merged output file can be specified explicitly with the `KCONFIG_CONFIG` environment variable; otherwise it just overwrites `.config`:

```
KCONFIG_CONFIG=some/path/.config ./scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh .config .config-fragment
```

Buildroot automates it with `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENT_FILES`: [How do I configure the Linux kernel within Buildroot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414968/how-do-i-configure-the-linux-kernel-within-buildroot)

Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19905/how-to-non-interactively-configure-the-linux-kernel-build Migrated 20 days earlier :-)

Comment: To create config snippets from changes made using menuconfig (remember to save the changes as `.config.new`): `make x86_x64_defconfig; make menuconfig; diff -u .config{,.new} | sed -ne '4,$s/^+//p' > config-snippet`

Answer (score 6):

Yes, some config options change names between releases, sometimes as an indication of subtle semantic changes.

I have written python classes to merge together a set of configuration fragments into base kernel configuration files.  That's overkill for you, though; you can do the same thing as a sed script; you aren't limited to one-liners.

```
sed -ir 's/^(CONFIG_XXX=.*|# CONFIG_XXX is not set)/CONFIG_XXX=m/;
         s/^(CONFIG_FOO=.*|# CONFIG_FOO is not set)/CONFIG_FOO=m/;
         s/^(CONFIG_BAR=.*|# CONFIG_BAR is not set)/CONFIG_BAR=m/' .config
```

Or even create a separate script. Say, config.sed that contains the lines:

```
s/^(CONFIG_XXX=.*|# CONFIG_XXX is not set)/CONFIG_XXX=m/;
s/^(CONFIG_FOO=.*|# CONFIG_FOO is not set)/CONFIG_FOO=m/;
s/^(CONFIG_BAR=.*|# CONFIG_BAR is not set)/CONFIG_BAR=m/;
```

Then you can run

```
sed -ire config.sed .config
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1 Thanks for the reply and the additional ideas. I was just mulling parsing the Kconfig files to get the *actual* dependencies, but as you say, that might be overkill.

Comment: Ah, for that you might want to use the non-interactive configuration patches. I think that Arjan van de Ven orginally wrote them for the Red Hat kernel many years ago, and we used a variant of them for the rPath kernels.  Probably easiest to pick them up out of the current Fedora kernel SRPMs; I think they are still there. That will take defaults after applying your changes, which will probably do what you want.

Comment: `-ire config.sed` does not work under GNU sed, it prefers the expressions in-line. `sed -i -re "``cat ../../config.sed``" .config` is the one that works for me. Note that the double backtick is a single one is real life, I only use it here to escape.

Comment: `scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh` is a built-in script that also uses `sed`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39440863/895245

Comment: I was struggling with this for quite a while. I needed to put `-r` as a separate argument instead of in the short argument cluster. My GNU `sed` as of Ubuntu 16.x+ was thinking `r` was the backup file extension argument to `-i` and not "use extended regex"!

Answer (score 4):

To do a series of simple flipping of a single config while updating any and all config dependencies:

### Single Option approach

```sh
./scripts/config --set-val CONFIG_OPTION y
./scripts/config --enable CONFIG_BRIDGE
./scripts/config --enable CONFIG_MODULES
./scripts/config --disable CONFIG_X25
./scripts/config --module CONFIG_NFT
make oldconfig
(updates dependencies; may prompt with new dependencies, but old deps silently goes away)
```

### Multiple-File Merge approach

If you have several small snippets of `.config-*` files that you want to selectively merge into the main `.config` file, execute:

```sh
# Merge IP fragment CONFIG_ settings into the main .config file
./scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh .config .config-fragment
# Merge  Notebook HW-specific CONFIG_ settings into main .config file
./scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh .config .config-notebook-toshiba

# Auto-add/auto-remove CONFIG_ dependencies
make oldconfig
```

## References

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/kconfig.html#nconfig-mode
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090431/linux-kconfig-command-line-interface/70728869#70728869](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70728869/4379130)