# linux kconfig command line interface

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, makefile, kernel, kbuild

My goal is to change kbuild configs using the command line without messing up dependencies.

For this I've created a 'reference' config by editing my default `.config` with `make menuconfig`. The 'only' thing I've changed was changing from 64 bit to 32 bit.

Now I took my original config and applied the following command (from the linux kernel root directory)

```
scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh original.conf 32bit.conf
```

The content of `32bit.conf` is simply `CONFIG_64=n`.

After diffing the two `.config`s from `make menuconfig` and my command I see that almost every change from `make menuconfig` is also present in the other file. But only *almost* every change.

```
$ diff .config.mkmenuconfig .config.command
104d103
< # CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL is not set
112d110
< # CONFIG_VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN is not set
327d324
< # CONFIG_MPSC is not set
330d326
< # CONFIG_GENERIC_CPU is not set
345c341,342
< # CONFIG_HPET_TIMER is not set
---
> CONFIG_HPET_TIMER=y
> CONFIG_HPET_EMULATE_RTC=y
```

Where are these differences from and is there an official way to manipulate kbuild `.config`s via command line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you non-interactively turn on features in a Linux kernel .config file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505164/how-do-you-non-interactively-turn-on-features-in-a-linux-kernel-config-file)

Answer (score 0):

As of 5.2+ Linux kernel, CONFIG can take in a second file of `.config` and auto-merge them into a final `.config`.

But first, on a slightly related note on differences of config file, to show differences from your old `.config` to what is newly issued by the Linux kernel, execute:

```sh
make listnewconfig
(outputs a list of CONFIG_* that are newly added over old .config)
```

## List of Config Files

Use the '`KCONFIG_DEFCONFIG_LIST`' shell define to be read by `make` utility which containing a list of files, each separated by whitespace.

`config.network` would be in the same directory as the `Makefile` of Linux kernel.

```
CONFIG_BRIDGE=y
CONFIG_ARP=y
CONFIG_IP=y
CONFIG_IP6=y
```

and `config.notebook-toshiba` may have

```
CONFIG_SCSI=y
CONFIG_AHCI=y
CONFIG_RTC_INTF_DEV=y
```

then execute:

```sh
KCONFIG_DEFCONFIG_LIST="config.network config.notebook-toshiba" make bzImage modules
```

## Miniconfig Method

(partially based on lkml email from/by Rob Landley, re: miniconfig)

The `allyesconfig`/`allmodconfig`/`allnoconfig`/`randconfig` variants can also use the environment variable `KCONFIG_ALLCONFIG` as a flag or a filename that contains config symbols that the user requires to be set to a specific value.

If `KCONFIG_ALLCONFIG` is used without a filename where `KCONFIG_ALLCONFIG == “”` or `KCONFIG_ALLCONFIG == “1”`, make *config checks for a file named “`all{yes/mod/no/def/random}.config`” (corresponding to the *config command that was used) for symbol values that are to be forced.

If this file is not found, it checks for a file named “all.config” to contain forced values.

This enables you to create “miniature” config (`miniconfig`) or custom config files containing just the config symbols that you are interested in. Then the kernel config system generates the full `.config` file, including symbols of your miniconfig file.

This ‘`KCONFIG_ALLCONFIG`’ file is a config file which contains (usually a subset of all) preset config symbols. These variable settings are still subject to normal dependency checks.

Examples:

```sh
KCONFIG_ALLCONFIG=custom-notebook.config make allnoconfig
```

or:

```sh
KCONFIG_ALLCONFIG=mini.config make allnoconfig
```

or:

```sh
make KCONFIG_ALLCONFIG=mini.config allnoconfig
```

These examples will disable most options (allnoconfig) but enable or disable the options that are explicitly listed in the specified mini-config files.

## Reference

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/kconfig.html#nconfig-mode