# What exactly does Linux kernel's `make defconfig` do?

Tags: linux-kernel, kbuild

I can use the following command to create a Linux kernel `.config` file based on a specified architecture default for a custom ARM-based board:

```
ARCH=arm make defconfig KBUILD_DEFCONFIG=var_som_mx6_android_defconfig
```

I thought that this command more or less copies `./arch/arm/configs/var_som_mx6_android_defconfig` to `./.config`.  However the resulting `.config` file isn't exactly a copy:

```
$ diff --unified arch/arm/configs/var_som_mx6_android_defconfig  .config
--- arch/arm/configs/var_som_mx6_android_defconfig  2017-01-20 12:10:51.891515984 -0800
+++ .config 2017-01-26 15:31:29.000000000 -0800
@@ -407,6 +407,7 @@
 CONFIG_ARM_ERRATA_751472=y
 CONFIG_ARM_ERRATA_794072=y
 CONFIG_ARM_ERRATA_761320=y
+CONFIG_ARM_ERRATA_845369=y
 # CONFIG_ARM_ERRATA_753970 is not set
 CONFIG_ARM_ERRATA_754322=y
 # CONFIG_ARM_ERRATA_754327 is not set
@@ -2683,7 +2684,6 @@
 CONFIG_AUTOFS4_FS=y
 CONFIG_FUSE_FS=y
 # CONFIG_CUSE is not set
-CONFIG_AUFS_FS=y

 #
 # Caches
@@ -2759,6 +2759,21 @@
 # CONFIG_PSTORE is not set
 # CONFIG_SYSV_FS is not set
 # CONFIG_UFS_FS is not set
+CONFIG_AUFS_FS=y
+CONFIG_AUFS_BRANCH_MAX_127=y
+# CONFIG_AUFS_BRANCH_MAX_511 is not set
+# CONFIG_AUFS_BRANCH_MAX_1023 is not set
+# CONFIG_AUFS_BRANCH_MAX_32767 is not set
+CONFIG_AUFS_SBILIST=y
+# CONFIG_AUFS_HNOTIFY is not set
+# CONFIG_AUFS_RDU is not set
+# CONFIG_AUFS_PROC_MAP is not set
+# CONFIG_AUFS_SP_IATTR is not set
+# CONFIG_AUFS_SHWH is not set
+# CONFIG_AUFS_BR_RAMFS is not set
+# CONFIG_AUFS_BR_FUSE is not set
+CONFIG_AUFS_BDEV_LOOP=y
+# CONFIG_AUFS_DEBUG is not set
 CONFIG_NETWORK_FILESYSTEMS=y
 CONFIG_NFS_FS=y
 CONFIG_NFS_V3=y
```

I don't understand where the extra lines are coming from, and I have always found the internal workings of the kernel configuration, makefiles, and build scripts to be difficult to understand.  Can anyone explain where those lines in the `.config` might be coming from?

Comment: related: oldconfig: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178526/what-does-make-oldconfig-do-exactly-in-the-linux-kernel-makefile/31936064#31936064

Comment: @CiroSantilli包子露宪六四事件法轮功: thanks - I have never heard of that before.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

### Motivation

The `.config` file is not simply copied from your `defconfig` file. The motivation for storing `defconfig` in such a format is next: in `defconfig` we can specify only options with non-default values (i.e. options we changed for our board). This way we can keep it small and clear. Every new kernel version brings a bunch of new options, and this way we don't need to update our `defconfig` file each time the kernel releases. Also, it should be mentioned that kernel build system keeps very specific order of options in `defconfig` file, so it's better to avoid modifying it by hand. Instead you should use `make savedefconfig` rule.

### Simplified explanation

When `.config` file is being generated, kernel build system goes through all `Kconfig` files (from all subdirs), checking all options in those `Kconfig` files:

- if option is mentioned in `defconfig`, build system puts that option into `.config` with value chosen in `defconfig`
- if option isn't mentioned in `defconfig`, build system puts that option into `.config` using its default value, specified in corresponding `Kconfig`

Check [scripts/kconfig/Makefile](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9/source/scripts/kconfig/Makefile#L98) and [scripts/kconfig/conf.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9/source/scripts/kconfig/conf.c#L665) files to see how it's actually done.

### More precise and detailed explanation

From ["Kbuild: the Linux Kernel Build System" by Javier Martinez](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/kbuild-linux-kernel-build-system):

> **Defining Configuration Symbols: `Kconfig` Files**
>
> Configuration symbols are defined in files known as `Kconfig` files. Each `Kconfig` file can describe an arbitrary number of symbols and can also include (source) other `Kconfig` files. Compilation targets that construct configuration menus of kernel compile options, such as `make menuconfig`, read these files to build the tree-like structure. Every directory in the kernel has one `Kconfig` that includes the `Kconfig` files of its subdirectories. On top of the kernel source code directory, there is a `Kconfig` file that is the root of the options tree. The `menuconfig` (`scripts/kconfig/mconf`), `gconfig` (`scripts/kconfig/gconf`) and other compile targets invoke programs that start at this root `Kconfig` and recursively read the `Kconfig` files located in each subdirectory to build their menus. Which subdirectory to visit also is defined in each `Kconfig` file and also depends on the config symbol values chosen by the user.
>
> **Storing Symbol Values: `.config` File**
>
> All config symbol values are saved in a special file called `.config`. Every time you want to change a kernel compile configuration, you execute a make target, such as `menuconfig` or `xconfig`. These read the `Kconfig` files to create the menus and update the config symbols' values using the values defined in the `.config` file. Additionally, these tools update the `.config` file with the new options you chose and also can generate one if it didn't exist before.
>
> Because the `.config` file is plain text, you also can change it without needing any specialized tool. It is very convenient for saving and restoring previous kernel compilation configurations as well.

### Useful commands

You can use simpler syntax for `make defconfig`, like:

```
$ make ARCH=arm your_board_defconfig
```

See the full list of available defconfigs with:

```
$ make ARCH=arm help | grep defconfig
```

If you need to do reverse action (i.e. create a neat small `defconfig` from extensive `.config`), you can use `savedefconfig` rule:

```
$ make ARCH=arm savedefconfig
```

Also, as **0andriy** mentioned, you can use `diffconfig` script to see changes from one `.config` to another one:

```
$ scripts/diffconfig .config_old .config_new
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer (and the link to an article that I'm surprised I didn't come across already).  While waiting for some replies I had already figured that the additional lines came from validating the config through the Kconfig files, but this answer gives me so much more information and  better understanding.  Thanks again.

Comment: So in short, `make defconfig KBUILD_DEFCONFIG=var_som_mx6_android_defconfig` is the same as `make var_som_mx6_android_defconfig`, and so you basically never want to use `make defconfig` as it is more verbose.

Comment: I've received a pre-configured kernel tarball. On untarring and examining the `.config` file, I can see it was targetted at the vexpress board. However is there a `make` way to check which exact defconfig was it configured with?

Comment: @HighOnMeat You can use `scripts/diffconfig` with `-m` option to compare your `.config` file with each defconfig file from `arch/arm/configs/` directory (if your architecture is ARM32). Or you can use `make savedefconfig` rule to obtain `defconfig` file from your `config`, and then compare it with each defconfig using `diff` tool. Using `diffconfig` script is probably a better idea, as some defconfig files could be out of sync, as compared to `make savedefconfig` output. I don't know any automatic way to tell which defconfig was used originally, but it's not too hard to come up with one.

Comment: @SamProtsenko so this means this script can be embedded inside of another bash script to do the grunt work. We do not want to do this manually. I believe this script can be called from such a bash script right?

Comment: @HighOnMeat The point is, you can change the kernel whatever you like, it can work in many ways. But it will be only your local changes on top of kernel. Ideally you should do that in upstreamable way, and actually upstream it. And what is the right way that will satisfy everyone -- it's entirely another question. Btw, I think it's better to actually ask i on SO as a separate question :)

Comment: "if option isn't mentioned in defconfig, build system puts that option into .config using its default value, specified in corresponding Kconfig" But it looks like for some options no default value is specified in Kconfig.

Comment: @xiaokaoy If there is no default specified, it's `n` (default's default). Please see documentation for details: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/kconfig-language.html

Comment: @xiaokaoy "But it looks like some options are not specified in Kconfig" -- can you provide some example please?

Comment: Thanks. There was some typo in my first comment. Just ignore it. I didn't know I could delete it. Sorry about that. I've just removed it. Your answer is great.

Answer (score 4):

It also generates `include/generated/autoconf.h`.

This header file is included by C source files. On the other hand, `.config` is for the Makefile system.

The build system generates two files, and keeps them consistent.