# KBUILD_DEFCONFIG_KMACHINE ?= defconfig_file does not work as expected

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto

`KBUILD_DEFCONFIG_KMACHINE ?= defconfig_file` does not work as I expected.

**First lesson I learned: `defconfig != .config`**

Bare-Kernel-Build (without yocto): A new defconfig file below `arch/arm/config/xy_defconfig` created by `make savedefconfig` is not equal to the `.config` file. I assume the linux kernel expand some symbols and create the final `.config`.

Yocto-Build: Here comes the issue: Yocto can not correctly handle the defconfig file below `arch/arm/config/xy_defconfig`. When building the linux-kernel with yocto.. the kernel is half size and not bootable. This results, because yocto does not expand the missing symbols in .config, which a `make defconfig` would do.

How do you handle the issue?

**Update:**

Figured out an additional `make xy_defconfig` do the trick and creates the correct .config file. It is a ugly hack, any better ideas are very welcome.

Added this to my custom `linux-xy.bb` file.

```
KBUILD_DEFCONFIG ?= xy_defconfig

do_makedefconfig() {
     oe_runmake -C ${B} ARCH=${ARCH} $KBUILD_DEFCONFIG
}

addtask do_makedefconfig after do_configme before do_compile
```

Answer (score 5):

1. First copy your defconfig to sources/meta-mylayer/recipes-kernel/linux
   and write a .bbappend file for linux recipe

linux-ti_%.bbappend

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend : "${THISDIR}:"
SRC_URI += "file://your-defconfig"
```

2. open sources/meta-mylayer/conf/machine/your-machine.conf add below line,
search the macro if already present or nor using `grep -inr "INTREE_DEFCONFIG"`

```
INTREE_DEFCONFIG_pn-linux-ti = "am335x_phytec_defconfig"
```

if the macro already present in the same file replace defconfig name.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but this is exactly I do not want. During development  the defconfig-file could change.. so the valid defconfig-file is always in-tree and should not be delivered as a copy in the yocto-recipe. Otherwise, you always have to manually update recipe..

Answer (score 2):

### `kernel-yocto` approach

The `KBUILD_DEFCONFIG` variable is handled by `kernel-yocto` class, so you need to inherit it. It is usually done indirectly through include file `linux-yocto.inc`, so you should have this line you linux recipe:

```
require recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto.inc
```

Please note that `KBUILD_DEFCONFIG_KMACHINE` consists of two parts. The first one is variable name (`KBUILD_DEFCONFIG`) and the second one is kernel machine override (`KMACHINE`). So you need to change the override to fit your machine. That's why the `KMACHINE` part is written in italics in the documentation [1]. There is an example for RPi from the documentation:

```
KBUILD_DEFCONFIG_raspberrypi2 = "bcm2709_defconfig"
```

The `KMACHINE` is set in `linux-yocto.inc` to the `MACHINE` variable by default.

### handle in-tree defconfig by hand

We are using in-tree defconfig without the `kernel-yocto` class. `linux.inc` from `meta-oe` layer is used. I don't know if this is a best practice. Here is our linux recipe (it is reduced to a bare minimum):

```
require recipes-kernel/linux/linux.inc

PV = "your_version"
SRC_URI = "your_sources"

do_configure_prepend() {
    bbnote "Copying defconfig"
    cp ${S}/arch/${ARCH}/configs/YOUR_defconfig ${WORKDIR}/defconfig
}
```

---

[1] https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-KBUILD_DEFCONFIG

Comment: Thx for the reply, but you also did not get my point. `YOUR_defconfig` is not equal to  the `.config`, which results, when you first time run: `make ARCH=arm YOUR_defconfig` in a bare kernel-build. My expierience is, that Yocto is not able to expand the `defconfig` to a complete `.config` file. All those build trials result in a non-working kernel, with half size of the bare-build. Please see my update.. in the original question.

Comment: @johns. Just an idea - do you have correct KERNEL_IMAGETYPE (ie. compressed/uncompressed type)? Because half sized kernel image is really strange. BTW: the explanation why defconfig != .config is in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885015/what-exactly-does-linux-kernels-make-defconfig-do . And one more point: see `meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-kernel/linux/linux.inc` (if used) - it updates a kernel configuration a bit based on your OpenEmbedded configuration.