# Beaglebone / Yocto / Kernel configuration

Tags: linux, yocto, beagleboneblack

I want to change Kernel configuration.

I have my own layer created and inside my layer I have a `_%.bbappend` file which directly targets the recipe `linux-ti-staging.bb` ([link](https://github.com/YoeDistro/meta-ti/blob/dunfell/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-ti-staging_5.10.bb)). This recipe builds my kernel:

```
ziga@host:~/yocto/$ oe-pkgdata-util lookup-recipe kernel
linux-ti-staging
```

The recipe is part of the official layer `meta-ti` ([link](https://github.com/YoeDistro/meta-ti/tree/dunfell)).

My layer looks like this:

```
002--layers/meta--001/
├── conf
│   ├── distro
│   │   └── distro.conf
│   ├── layer.conf
│   └── machine
│       └── photovolt.conf
├── recipes-all
│   ├── application
│   │   └── application.bb
│   ├── image-003
│   │   └── image-003.bb
│   └── qtbase
│       └── qtbase_%.bbappend
├── recipes-bsp
│   └── u-boot
│       ├── u-boot-ti-staging
│       │   ├── 0001--add-fotovolt-dts-to-makefile.patch
│       │   └── photovolt.dts
│       └── u-boot-ti-staging_%.bbappend
└── recipes-kernel
    └── linux
        ├── linux-ti-staging
        │   ├── 0001--add-photovolt-dts-to-makefile.patch
        │   ├── 0002--disable-hdmi-node.patch
        │   ├── 0003--remove-conflicting-mmc-pinmuxing.patch
        │   ├── defconfig
        │   ├── fragment.cfg
        │   └── photovolt.dts
        └── linux-ti-staging_%.bbappend
```

---

I tried to follow the official Yocto reference ([link](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/kernel-dev/common.html#configuring-the-kernel)) to configure my `_%.bbappend` file in one of the two ways described there.

### 1st  - using configuration fragment

First, I tried to use a Linux kernel fragment. I executed:

```
ziga@host:~/yocto/$ bitbake -c menuconfig linux-ti-staging
```

made my configuration in kconfig/curses interface and saved the configuration under a default name `.config`. Then I created a Linux configuration fragment:

```
ziga@host:~/yocto/$ bitbake -c diffconfig linux-ti-staging
```

Fragment was created and it looks like this:

```
ziga@host:~/yocto/$ cat 003--builds/001--fotovolt/tmp/work/fotovolt-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-ti-staging/5.10.65+gitAUTOINC+dcc6bedb2c-r22b/fragment.cfg
CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_ST1232=y
```

I copied this fragment to my layer as can be seen from the first code snippet. Now according to the official reference I also created the `linux-ti-staging_%.bbappend` *(is detected by `bitbake-layers`)* with this content:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/linux-ti-staging:"
SRC_URI += "file://fragment.cfg"
```

I hoped that Yocto might treat a `fragment.cfg` file similar as patches, but it didn't do anything.

---

### 2nd - using an entire configuration

Secondly, I tried to use an entire Linux kernel configuration. I executed:

```
ziga@host:~/yocto/$ bitbake -c menuconfig linux-ti-staging
```

made my configuration in kconfig/curses interface and saved the configuration under a diferent name i.e. `defconfig` *(7234 lines)*:

```
ziga@host:~/yocto/$ wc -l 003--builds/001--fotovolt/tmp/work/fotovolt-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-ti-staging/5.10.65+gitAUTOINC+dcc6bedb2c-r22b/build/.config
7234
```

I copied this `defconfig` in my layer as can be seen from the first fragment of code. I then edited my `linux-ti-staging_%.bbappend` acccording to the official Yocto reference manual like this:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/linux-ti-staging:"
SRC_URI += "file://defconfig"
KCONFIG_MODE = "alldefconfig"
```

But this also did not work.

---

### I cleaned before building

In both cases I used two commands to cleanly build everything:

```
bitbake -c cleansstate virtual/kernel
bitbake image-003
```

But this does absolutely nothing to the kernel configuration. I can verify that no changes were applied by (a) logging in a running target, (b) extracting the `/proc/config.gz` somewhere and (c) read the obtained `config`  file. File is identical as it was...

So, how can I permanently modify the kernel configuration?

---

### Machine

My `MACHINE` is defined in `photovolt.conf` which basically reuses machine `beaglebone` ([link](https://github.com/YoeDistro/meta-ti/blob/dunfell/conf/machine/beaglebone.conf)) from official layer `meta-ti`. It looks like this:

```
#@TYPE: Machine
#@NAME: Photovolt machine - Beaglebone based machine
#@DESCRIPTION: Machine configuration for my machine

require conf/machine/beaglebone.conf

KERNEL_DEVICETREE = "photovolt.dtb"
UBOOT_MACHINE = "photovolt_defconfig"
```

---

### Distribution

Distribution that I use is defined in a `distro.conf` like this:

```
require conf/distro/poky.conf

DISTRO = "distro"
DISTRO_NAME = "Distro (Yocto derived GNU/Linux distribution)"
DISTRO_VERSION = "1.0.0"
DISTRO_CODENAME = "Heart I"
MAINTAINER = "Me <me.me@gmail.com>"
  
DISTRO_FEATURES:append = " systemd"
DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED = "sysvinit"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME:init_manager = "systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME:initscripts = ""
   
PREFERRED_PROVIDER:virtual/libgbm = "mesa"
```

---

### Recipe looks weird

Recipe `linux-ti-stagging.bb` ([link](https://github.com/YoeDistro/meta-ti/blob/dunfell/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-ti-staging_5.10.bb)) looks simple at a first glance, but it does some fishy things. It first `requires` a `setup-defconfig.inc` ([link](https://github.com/YoeDistro/meta-ti/blob/dunfell/recipes-kernel/linux/setup-defconfig.inc)) which has a task `do_configure()`. Here it does some copy operations where it also uses a weird `defconfig` file ([link](https://github.com/YoeDistro/meta-ti/blob/dunfell/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-ti-staging-5.10/defconfig)). Maybe this is somehow connected to my problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is obvious in `setup-defconfig.inc` that they handle config fragments in `do_configure` with this part:

```
# Fourth, handle config fragments specified in the recipe
    # The assumption is that the config fragment will be specified with the absolute path.
    # E.g. ${WORKDIR}/config1.cfg or ${S}/config2.cfg
    if [ -n "${KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENTS}" ]
    then
        for f in ${KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENTS}
        do
            # Check if the config fragment is available
            if [ ! -e "$f" ]
            then
                echo "Could not find kernel config fragment $f"
                exit 1
            fi
        done
    fi

    # Now that all the fragments are located merge them
    if [ -n "${KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENTS}" -o -n "$configfrags" ]
    then
        ( cd ${WORKDIR} && ${S}/scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh -m -r -O ${B} ${B}/.config $configfrags ${KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENTS} 1>&2 )
        yes '' | oe_runmake -C ${S} O=${B} oldconfig
    fi
```

So, here is the explanation of what it does:

- It checks if the variable `KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENTS` has a content
- If yes, it checks if its content (files) exist
- Merge all config fragments of and `KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENTS` and `configfrags` into `${B}/.config` which is the final configuration that will be built

`configfrags` just used to hold extracted fragments from other defconfig file. It does not matter for your case.

So, here what you can do in `linux-ti-staging_%.bbappend`:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI += "file://fragment.cfg"
KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENTS += "${WORKDIR}/fragment.cfg"
```

Since they are checking directly on the content of `KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENTS` it will fail if you set it without `${WORKDIR}`.

`${WORKDIR}` is where `fragment.cfg` will be unpacked.

So, based on what they are using on `do_configure`, the test on `KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENTS` should pass because it will have content, and it will merge its config into the configuration file `${B}/.config`.

To check that, after `do_configure` just check the content of `${B}/.config` for your new fragment content.

**ALERT**
YOU NEED TO LEFT THE FIRST LINE IN THE FRAGMENT FILE AS EMPTY LINE. BECAUSE `merge_config.sh` WILL SKIP IT.

So, your fragment will look like the following:

```
CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_ST1232=y
```

If that did not work, try to add this custom function to apply your fragment.cfg into the final configuration file:

- **linux-ti-staging_%.bbappend**:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI += "file://fragment.cfg"

CUSTOM_FRAGMENTS += "fragment.cfg"

do_merge_fragment(){
   for f in ${CUSTOM_FRAGMENTS}; do
       if [ -f "${WORKDIR}/${f}" ]; then
           ${S}/scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh -m ${B}/.config ${WORKDIR}/${f}
       fi
   done
}

addtask merge_fragment after do_configure before do_compile
```

With that you will make sure that the fragment will be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Your directory structure should be like this

```
meta-something
└── recipes-kernel
    └── linux
        ├── files
        │   └── defconfig
        └── linux-ti-staging.bbappend
```

And `linux-ti-staging.bbappend`

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI += "file://defconfig"
```

Comment: I did like you said. It is written in the reference [here](http://I%20read%20the%20recipe%20(%5Blink%5D%5B1%5D),%20but%20I%20don%27t%20understand,%20how%20I%20can%20modify%20it%20in%20order%20to%20use%20my%20Kernel%20configuration%20file.%20The%20recipe%20uses:%20%20%20%20%20%20require%20recipes-kernel/linux/setup-defconfig.inc%20%20that%20requires%20the%20%60setup-defconfig.inc%60%20(%5Blink%5D%5B3%5D).%20This%20file%20is%20actually%20responsible%20for%20creating%20the%20Linux%20configuration!%20But%20it%20is%20a%20bit%20complex%20and%20I%20am%20not%20a%20Python%20expert.). But fails!

Comment: I tried with an entire configuration and configuration fragment... Just like official reference says. But in both cases I was unsuccessfull. I suspect that recipe for `linux-ti-staging` is doing something fishy. It `requires` this `.inc` file ([link](https://github.com/YoeDistro/meta-ti/blob/master/recipes-kernel/linux/setup-defconfig.inc)) and then inside the `do_configure()` uses another file ([link](https://github.com/YoeDistro/meta-ti/blob/master/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-ti-staging-5.10/defconfig)). Somehow this manages completely ignore anything I do.

Comment: I read [here](https://yocto.yoctoproject.narkive.com/OePFc5zo/kernel-config-fragments-are-not-applied#post2) that if kernel recipe inherits directly from the class `kernel.bblass`, kernel configuration fragments will not work. This is what recipe `linux-ti-staging` also does. So what can be done in this case?

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441494/kbuild-defconfig-kmachine-defconfig-file-does-not-work-as-expected) is interesting...

Comment: I also added details about the machine & distribution.