# How u-boot generation the dot config file

Tags: config, u-boot, kbuild

Under the u-boot tree, after `make my_defconfig`, a `.config` is generated. By comparing the defconfig and dot config files, it seems that all config items in `my_defconfig` are included in `.config`, and there are some extra config items added into `.config`. I am wondering where are those extra config items come from?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration options are defined in the Kconfig files. The defconfig file just replaces the entries that you could make in

```
make menuconfig
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found out that my question was kind of duplicated: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885015/what-exactly-does-linux-kernels-make-defconfig-do> contains some more detailed answer I was looking for (u-boot borrows kbuild from linux). Thanks again!