# Why is my kernel configuration option not set in resulting defconfig after running bitbake -c savedefconfig virtual/kernel?

Tags: embedded-linux, splash-screen, yocto, bitbake

I have made some adjustments to the kernel source so that I can use a custom logo on the kernel splash screen. In particular, the changes I have made allow the custom logo to be chosen as a kernel configuration option when I run the following bitbake command:

```
bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel
```

and then navigate to the Device Drivers > Graphics support -> Bootup logo. I set the Bootup logo to the custom logo, save my changes & exit menuconfig. At this point, the generated .config file is at tmp/work/imx6ul_var_dart-fslc-linux-gnueabi/linux-variscite/4.9.88-r0/build/.config and I confirm that my logo has been configured as the boot logo in the following line from the .config file:

```
CONFIG_LOGO_CUSTOM_CLUT224=y
```

All is good up to this point. Now, I want to save the .config file in a defconfig format so that I can overwrite the default configuration in the source tree and replace it with the generated defconfig file. To do this I run the following command:

```
bitbake -c savedefconfig virtual/kernel
```

At this point, the generated defconfig file is at tmp/work/imx6ul_var_dart-fslc-linux-gnueabi/linux-variscite/4.9.88-r0/build/defconfig. But, when I search the generated defconfig file...I do not find the following line:

```
CONFIG_LOGO_CUSTOM_CLUT224=y
```

Why am I not seeing this configuration option in the defconfig file even though it was set in the .config file it is being generated from?

Edit (adding extra info):

I will describe the precise changes made to the kernel source. Firstly, I added the logo (logo_custom_clut224.ppm) to drivers/video/logo. I then modified drivers/video/logo/Kconfig to include the following entry inside `if LOGO` and the corresponding `endif` :

```
config LOGO_CUSTOM_CLUT224
    bool "224-color Custom logo"
    default y
```

I then added the following logic to drivers/video/logo/logo.c inside the `if (depth >= 8)` block:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_LOGO_CUSTOM_CLUT224
    logo = &logo_custom_clut224;
#endif
```

I then added the following statement to include/linux/linux_logo.h:

```
extern const struct linux_logo logo_custom_clut224;
```

Lastly, I modified the drivers/video/logo/Makefile to include an entry for the custom logo:

```
obj-$(CONFIG_LOGO_CUSTOM_CLUT224 += logo_custom_clut224.o
```

I would also like to note that the logo I am trying to use is 800x480.

Comment: Have you tried this and the splashscreen does not appear or are you just wondering why the configuration item does not show up in `defconfig`? `savedefconfig` will skip non-optional, boolean choices equal to 'y' that match the original default. `defconfig` is supposed to be a minimal `.config`.

Comment: I have tried it and the splashscreen does not appear. But, I am mainly wondering why the item does not show up in defconfig. Edit: I suspect the splashscreen is not appearing because it is not showing up in defconfig.

Comment: That is probably not the case. Like I said, it is not showing up in the `defconfig` because the value in `.config` matches the default value from `Kconfig`. You should try changing it to `n` and the generating the `defconfig`, to actually see it in the `defconfig`. 

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41886394/7025024 for further details. Also, the Yocto Project Manual talks about the `Configuring the Kernel` and discusses `.config` and `defconfig`.

Another question, did you disable the logo you are trying to replace?