Built-In I2C driver not registering or init
I'm new to Linux other than going through a crash course on Linux. I am trying to add a I2C device driver into kernel 4.19. In the driver's *.c file I think I've added in the prerequisites. Here's a snippet.
static const struct i2c_device_id foo_i2c_id[] = {
    { "foo", 0 },
    {}
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(i2c, foo_i2c_id);

static const struct of_device_id foo_i2c_match[] = {
    { .compatible = "bar,foo" },
    {}
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, foo_i2c_match);

static struct i2c_driver foo_i2c_driver = {
    .driver = {
        .name = foo,
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,
        .of_match_table = of_match_ptr(foo_i2c_match),
    },
    .probe    = foo_i2c_probe,
    .remove   = foo_i2c_remove,
    .id_table = foo_i2c_id,
};

static int __init foo_ctl_init(void)
{
    int ret = 0;

    ret = i2c_add_driver(&foo_i2c_driver);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printk("%s: i2c driver register failed.\n", __func__);
    } else {
        printk("%s: i2c driver register SUCCESS.\n", __func__);
    }

    return ret;
}
device_initcall(foo_ctl_init);

MODULE_DESCRIPTION("foo driver");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL v2");

In the Makefile of the same directory I've added in this. It's in sound/soc/codecs/ as it's a sound device that's controlled via I2C.
obj-$(CONFIG_SND_SOC_FOO) += foo_driver.o

Then in the Kconfig I've added in this. Which I don't think does much since I'm enabling it via defconfig.
config SND_SOC_FOO
    tristate "Foo driver"
    depends on I2C

In defconfig it's this line. Using arch/arm64/configs/vendor/bengal_defconfig.
CONFIG_SND_SOC_FOO=y

Over at the DeviceTree side, I've added these. It's a Qualcomm Android board, and other devices in qupv3_se1_i2c is working. Also I was able to see foo show up in the i2c list (more on that later).
&qupv3_se1_i2c {
    foo@5d {
        status = "okay";
        compatible = "bar,foo";
        reg = <0x5d>;
    }
}

After compiling, I think the DeviceTree portion is fine as I am able to see the foo@5d device when query via the 2 commands:
ls -al /sys/bus/i2c/devices/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2024-09-09 22:25 0-0009 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/4a84000.i2c/i2c-0/0-0009
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2024-09-09 22:25 0-000e -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/4a84000.i2c/i2c-0/0-000e
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2024-09-09 22:25 0-000f -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/4a84000.i2c/i2c-0/0-000f
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2024-09-09 22:25 0-0022 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/4a84000.i2c/i2c-0/0-0022
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2024-09-09 22:25 0-0028 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/4a84000.i2c/i2c-0/0-0028
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2024-09-09 22:25 0-0042 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/4a84000.i2c/i2c-0/0-0042
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2024-09-09 22:25 0-0044 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/4a84000.i2c/i2c-0/0-0044
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2024-09-09 22:25 0-0045 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/4a84000.i2c/i2c-0/0-0045
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2024-09-09 22:25 0-005d -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/4a84000.i2c/i2c-0/0-005d
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2024-09-09 22:25 1-0014 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/4a88000.i2c/i2c-1/1-0014
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2024-09-09 22:25 1-002f -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/4a88000.i2c/i2c-1/1-002f
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2024-09-09 22:25 i2c-0 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/4a84000.i2c/i2c-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2024-09-09 22:25 i2c-1 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/4a88000.i2c/i2c-1
ls /proc/device-tree/soc/i2c@4a84000:
#address-cells  dma-names   phandle        qcom,wrapper-core     wsa881x-i2c-codec@e
#size-cells     dmas        pinctrl-0      reg                   wsa881x-i2c-codec@f
clock-names     fsa4480@42  pinctrl-1      status
clocks          interrupts  pinctrl-names  tca6424@22
compatible      name        qcom,pm8008@8  wsa881x-i2c-codec@44
foo@5d      nq@28       qcom,pm8008@9  wsa881x-i2c-codec@45

However, there was no logs related to the driver in dmesg.
Also I've tried sniffing the I2C lines with a logic analyzer. Was able to find the probe of other devices under qupv3_se1_i2c (their addresses shows up) but not 0x5d for the foo device.
Also, tried to do the following command, but not able to find anything regarding foo driver. From some Googling, seems to indicate that driver was not in kernel at all, especially since it's a built-in driver, not a ko module.
objdump -x vmlinux | grep foo

This leads me to speculate that the foo driver was never registered properly? Please advise or point me in some direction to investigate, thanks!
Edit 1: Fixed copy paste error in i2c_device_id and of_device_id.
Edit 2: Fixed copy paste error i2c_device_id foo has quotation marks. Also added the result of ls commands.

Several obvious issues with your "snippet". Your arrays of struct i2c_device_id and struct of_device_id are not properly constructed/terminated. Your struct i2c_driver is never exported/registered. Examine an existing i2c driver in the Linux kernel.

"In defconfig it's this line." - Manually editing a .config or xxx_defconfig file is a bad idea and discouraged. Proper procedure is to generate a custom build using make menuconfig, and then make savedefconfig for the new, revised defconfig  file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885015/what-exactly-does-linux-kernels-make-defconfig-do

@sawdust Thanks for catching the malformed array. It was my copy paste error and I have fixed it in the post.

@sawdust How does one register the i2c_driver? I have thought the i2c_add_driver(&foo_i2c_driver); in static int __init foo_ctl_init(void) would have done it?

Yes, what you have is enough, there is no need to export i2c_driver object instance.

To your main question, add initcall_debug to the kernel command line before booting it. In dmesg you will see it.

Is it enabled in the kernel build's .config?

@ShityCoder - One more time: examine existing i2c drivers. (There are more than 800 i2c drivers in version 4.19.) You have a slave device connected to a master controller. So device_initcall(foo_ctl_init); is incorrect. For  "registering a modular I2C driver" you are expected to use the macro module_i2c_driver() .

@sawdust, it's fine to have device_initcall(). I recommend you to study this better. You may start from here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.11/source/include/linux/module.h#L122. (Btw it's your second inaccurate comment here, perhaps you need to refresh your knowledge?)

@IanAbbott, he has a device in sysfs. It might be that it's connected to the different bus (I²C host controller) as there are two of them AFAICS. Second, they still need to add initcall_debug to the kernel command line, it will immediately show in dmesg what's going on WRT the driver initialisation. Also it might be that printk() without log level is not enabled, ignore_loglevel in the kernel command line should probably help with that.

@0andriy We have not seen evidence in sysfs that the device has a driver.

Does /sys/bus/i2c/devices/0-005d/driver exist?

@0andriy printk output without a loglevel will use the default loglevel and should still be shown by dmesg.

@IanAbbott only if the dmesg loglevel is high enough which might be not the case (if kernel command line has some tweaks, for example). Second point, I dunno why everybody here seems to ignore the simplest thing, i.e. initcall_debug kernel command line parameter)...

@0andriy ignore_loglevel and dmesg -n level only affect the filtering of log messages written to the console. A plain dmesg will show all the log messages in the ring buffer.
